# Dividing a column header

Tags: html

This is what I have tried:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Airlines</th>
    <th>Departure</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th colspan="2">Time</th>
    <th>Fare</th>
    
  <tr>
    <td>Buddha Air</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>7:55</td>
    <td>8:20</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Yeti Airlines</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>Jomsom</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Shree Airlines</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Dhangadhi</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Surya Air</td>
    <td>Biratnagar</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I want:

[image: Screenshot 1]

This I what I have now:

[image: Screenshot 2]

How can I divide the column header in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there! You just need to add another row for the subheadings (Departure and Arrival), then make all the other headings span both of those rows.

I've also grouped together your header and body rows using [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) for better legibility and standards compliance.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Airlines</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Departure</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Destination</th>
      <th colspan="2">Time</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Fare</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>Departure</th>
      <th>Arrival</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Buddha Air</td>
      <td>Kathmandu</td>
      <td>Pokhara</td>
      <td>7:55</td>
      <td>8:20</td>
      <td>3500</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Yeti Airlines</td>
      <td>Pokhara</td>
      <td>Jomsom</td>
      <td>8:15</td>
      <td>8:45</td>
      <td>3900</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Shree Airlines</td>
      <td>Kathmandu</td>
      <td>Dhangadhi</td>
      <td>11:15</td>
      <td>12:00</td>
      <td>8000</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Surya Air</td>
      <td>Biratnagar</td>
      <td>Kathmandu</td>
      <td>1:15</td>
      <td>1:55</td>
      <td>4200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so we can't do this without the putting all rowspan and colspan. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

I just added a new `tr` for the Arrival and Departure then use `colspan` and `rowspan` to adjust the size of theh `td`

```html
    <html>

<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Airlines</th>
    <th rowspan="3">Departure</th>
    <th rowspan="3">Destination</th>
    <th colspan="2">Time</th>
    <th rowspan="3">Fare</th>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td>Departure</td>
    <td>Arrival</td>
    
  </tr>
    <td>Buddha Air</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>7:55</td>
    <td>8:20</td>
    <td>3500</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yeti Airlines</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>Jomsom</td>
    <td>7:55</td>
    <td>8:20</td>
    <td>3500</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shree Airlines</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Dhangadhi</td>
    <td>7:55</td>
    <td>8:20</td>
    <td>3500</td>

  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td>Surya Air</td>
      <td>Biratnagar</td>
      <td>Kathmandu</td>
      <td>7:55</td>
      <td>8:20</td>
      <td>3500</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rowspan` for headers and you hould have two header rows

https://jsfiddle.net/7eq3ghat/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here Is my Answer... Added new <tr&gt <td> and set colspan = 2 for time column and set rowspan = 2 value for other remaining column.

```
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>

<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Airlines</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Departure</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Destination</th>
    <th colspan="2">Time</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Fare</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td >Departure</td>
    <td>Arrival</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Buddha Air</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>7:55</td>
    <td>8:20</td>
    <td>3500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yeti Airlines</td>
    <td>Pokhara</td>
    <td>Jomsom</td>
    <td>8:15</td>
    <td>8:45</td>
    <td>3900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Shree Airlines</td>
    <td>Kathmandu</td>
    <td>Dhangadhi</td>
    <td>11:15</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>8000</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td>Surya Air</td>
      <td>Biratnagar</td>
      <td>Kathmandu</td>
      <td>1:15</td>
      <td>1:55</td>
      <td>4200</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Result of the above code :

[image]